# Unable to delete data fusion instance due to "nested resource"

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to delete a Data Fusion instance. However when I use click the delete button I get the following error:

> Resource '' has nested resources. If the API supports cascading delete, set 'force' to true to delete it and its nested resources.

How do I find out what the `nested resources` are?

I also tried using the `gcloud` cli to delete it, but there's no indication how to to set `force` to true.